# filename.delete() function and filename.renameTo(newfilename) function not returning positive results

Tags: java

In my program, the `filename.delete()` and `filename.renameTo(newfilename)` functions always return `false`. My code:

```
    File file = new File("test.txt");
    File file1 = new File("test1.txt");
    boolean success1 = file.delete();
    boolean success2 = file1.renameTo(file);
    System.out.println(success1);
    System.out.println(success2);
```

Am I using them in the right way?

Comment: Use `Files.move(file1.toPath(), file.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)` instead.  Instead of a boolean, it gives you a full, informative exception if it fails.